# PySpark loading from URL

Tags: csv, url, download, pyspark

I wanted to load csv files from a URL in PySpark, is it even possible to do so?
I keep the files on GitHub.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is no naive way in pyspark (see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#external-datasets)). 
However, if you have a function that takes as input a URL and outputs the csv:

```
def read_from_URL(UR):
    # your logic here
    return data
```

You can use spark to parallelize this operation:

```
URL_list = ['http://github.com/file/location/file1.csv, ...]
data = sc.parallelize(URL_list).map(read_from_URL)
```